# Maximal solution of differential equation with separated variables

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

(a) Consider $x' = \cos(t) e^x = f(t,x)$.
First, $f$ is continuously differentiable and so is Lipschitz, therefore for every initial value we have exactly one solution.
By separation of variables I came up with the solution
$x(t) = -\ln(e^{-x_0} - \sin(t) + \sin(t_0))$.
Is this correct? I am a bit confused here, since this would mean that $x(t)$ is only defined on all of $\mathbb R$ if $e^{-x_0} > \sin (t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, that is, $e^{-x_0} > 1$. So for example for $x_0 = 0$ the maximal solution is not defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Is it correct that it is defined on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

(b) Consider $x' = \frac{x^2}{t+1}$. What is the interval of a maximal solution here? I would say it is given by $t > -1$ since my solution is not defined for $t \leq -1$. Correct? Again, since the RHS is locally Lipschitz (outside $t=-1$) there should exist a unique maximal solution for each initial value, right?

Answer (score 1):

**a))**: Your analysis is correct. If you take $x_0 = 0$, then the solution is given by $x(t) = - \text{ln}\left(1-\sin t\right)$. Note that you can infer that the maximal definition interval for this solution is $(-\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, which is larger than the interval stated in your question.

**b)** From the equation, it is clear that any interval of definition of a solution cannot extend beyond $t = -1$. Indeed, by the Existence and Uniqueness theorem, every initial value (apart from $t = -1$, obviously) will give rise to a unique maximal solution.
Solving the ODE yields $x(t) = \left(c + \text{ln}|1+t|\right)^{-1}$, which indeed shows that the maximal interval for any initial condition is either the semi-infinite interval $(-1,\infty)$ or the semi-infinite interval $(-\infty,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

(a)

[image: The solution in (a)]

Your solution is true and this does not contradict with Lipschitz condition. Because since $f$ satisfies Liptschitz we can say, every initial value problem is continuous. This does not conclude about the domain of the solution. It only says the solution is continuous.